# StdIn.readAll() vs. readString()

Tags: java, stdin

I was writing code to read string from a file. While using 
`String s = StdIn.readAll();` 
it worked fine. But I don't understand why, by using

```
while (!StdIn.readString().isEmpty())
    s = s.concat(StdIn.readString());
```

I got an `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error. Is it because the string is too long?

(I was using [this Stdln library](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html))

Thank you!

Comment: What do you think _each_ `readString` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the calls to `StdIn.readString()` reads another string. So, even if the string you read in the while condition isn't empty, you read (or try to read) another string inside the loop.

Store in a variable:

```
String r;
while (!(r = StdIn.readString()).isEmpty()) {
  s = s.concat(r);
}
```

Incidentally, a better approach than `concat` would just be to use `s += r`, or a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String r;
while (!(r = StdIn.readString()).isEmpty()) {
  sb.append(r);
}
s = sb.toString();
```